# Reverse function defined by me is not printing the result

Tags: c++

In int main() function if I use declare vector b is not printing the result. If I erase the vector b then the expected result is printed. Why the presence of vector b is obstructing the printing of reverse function?

I erase the vector b then the expected result is printed. The presence of vector b is obstructing the printing of reverse function

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int reverse(vector<int> a, int s, int e) {
    while(s < e) {
        int temp = a[s];
        a[s] = a[e - 1];
        a[e - 1] = temp;
        s++;
        e--;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    }
}

int main() {
    vector<int> a;

    a.push_back(1);
    a.push_back(3);
    a.push_back(5);
    a.push_back(7);
    a.push_back(9);

    vector<vector<int>> b;
    b[0].push_back(0);
    b[0].push_back(2);
    b[1].push_back(0);
    b[1].push_back(3);

    reverse(a, 0, 5);
}
```

Expected result: `9 7 5 3 1`
No error message but the expected result is not printed.

Comment: Using single-character names for variables other than loop counters is bad practice and makes for unreadable code. What are `s` and `e`? (I assume that they're start and end (+1) indices, but that's just from context)

Comment: `b[0]` invokes undefined behaviour.  There is no element zero.

Comment: Then what is the right way to declare vector b?

Comment: @BharathKarukola There's nothing wrong with your declaration of `b`, but `b` is empty so you shouldn't try to access elements in it. See my updated answer for some of the many possible fixes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your push `b[0].push_back(0);` is "illegal". `b` doesn't have element 0. Anything after that has [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) due to [access out of bounds](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub#Access_out_of_bounds).

You can fix it by creating `b` containing 2 default constructed `vector<int>`s

```
vector<vector<int>> b(2);
```

or by adding a default constructed `vector<int>` as you go:

```
vector<vector<int>> b;
b.emplace_back();
b.back().push_back(0);
b.back().push_back(2);
b.emplace_back();
b.back().push_back(0);
b.back().push_back(3);
```

or by preparing a temporary `vector<int>` that you then move into `b`.

```
vector<vector<int>> b;
vector<int> tmp;
tmp.push_back(0);
tmp.push_back(2);
b.emplace_back(std::move(tmp));
tmp.clear();
tmp.push_back(0);
tmp.push_back(3);
b.emplace_back(std::move(tmp));
tmp.clear();
```

Comment: Why are people upvoting this answer?  The question is a bad question, should be (and soon will be) closed, and should not be answered.

Comment: @MartinBonner Perhaps ... but even if a question _is_ bad (which I personally don't think one is) the answer may still be useful. It may be hard to search for help for a new guy in cases like this and I don't think suggesting to use a debugger would help either.